# I cannot access XAMP on an HP SERVER with 4 IP Addresses

Tags: apache, xampp

I have a problem accessing my XAMP server on an HP SERVER DL360G7 that has 4 IP address. Here are the networks.

172.22.46.x
and
172.22.7.x

I managed to access my site using the 172.22.7.x network. However, when I try to browse using any computer under the 172.22.46.x network, the server doesn't reply anything.

Here is my APACHE config

# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

```
#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride All

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
Require all granted
Require ip 172.22.46
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if apache is bound against any address instead of just 1 server IP. When you execute the function netstat -tupl in the console and search for httpd, does it bind to * or to a specific IP?

Else check your httpd.conf for the `Listen` command. There shouldn't be any specific IP if you want it to listen to all interfaces.

More info [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/bind.html)

Comment: Hi Paul, Im  not familiar with using the netstat -tupl in the console. However, here is my listen configuration
<code>
#
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80 </code>

Comment: yes it binds to the 172.22.7.200 which is the ip for the HP server

Comment: @drake24 You want the server to bind to all addresses I assume. Check out the link I gave earlier on binding and make sure it binds to all addresses. I'm pretty sure that'll fix your issue.

Comment: Ok thanks Paul. lastly, for example I want to bind the 172.22.46 network I'll just add Listen 192.22.46.x:80 ? or do I need just use three octets since I will be adding the whole 46.x network.

Comment: @drake24 the "Listen" directive basically tells on which SERVER IP's Apache will bind, if you want apache to bind on them all, simply only set "Listen 80" - or if you want to specify the specific ports/ip's add multiples, so "Listen ip1:80" and "Listen ip2:80" etc.

Comment: Still didn't work all I get is a "Server is taking too long to respond" on the 172.22.46 network :(